# Selenium does't work on Firefox 57 on php

Tags: php, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver

First of all I have installed **Selenium Server Standalone 3.9.1**, **XAMPP 3.2.2**, **php-webdriver 0.9.1** and **Firefox 57** and I want to run the **example.php** file from the root of the selenium folder. This is the code:

```
require_once "phpwebdriver/WebDriver.php";

$webdriver = new WebDriver("localhost", "4444");
$webdriver->connect("firefox");
$webdriver->get("http://google.com");
$element = $webdriver->findElementBy(LocatorStrategy::name, "q");
if ($element) {
    $element->sendKeys(array("php webdriver" ) );
    $element->submit();
}
```

When I run this code on a chrome page, firefox is opened, **google.com** is opened and it stops, it doesn't do anything. It should search in google search bar for **'php webdriver'** but it doesn't. I get the next notice on chrome page where I run this code:

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$ELEMENT in ...\WebDriver\phpwebdriver\WebElement.php on line 28

I've tried to:

- run the code with and without firefox version
- run the code with another browser (chrome) but there I get another error (**Undefined property: stdClass::$sessionId**)
- installed selenium server standalone 3.4.0

Nothing works! Can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The *Java Docs* of [**`sendKeys()`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#sendKeys-java.lang.CharSequence...-) method defines the method as  follows :

- **`sendKeys()`** :

  ```
  void sendKeys(java.lang.CharSequence... keysToSend)
  Use this method to simulate typing into an element, which may set its value.

  Parameters:
  keysToSend - character sequence to send to the element

  Throws:
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException - if keysToSend is null
  ```

So a quick solution will be to change the code block as follows  :

```
$element = $this->webdriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::name('q'));
if ($element) {
    $element->sendKeys(array('php webdriver') );
    $element->submit();
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work! I change it but now in WebElement.php on sendKeys() method throws an error if (!is_array($value)) {throw new Exception("$value must be an array");}. And if I comment this if statement I get the same notice!

Comment: Checkout my updated answer and let me know the status

Comment: So, first I get the error that I cannot use $this because it is not an object, after I delete $this I get another error because does not exist findElement() method, if I change it with findElementBy() I get the error that there is no class WebDriverBy and if I change it with WebDriver I get the error that there is no method name() in class WebDriver. So, it still doesn't work!